# SQLite3 - Why LEFT JOIN differs from other RDBMSes?

Tags: sqlite, left-join

For example, two tables have has many (or has one) relation. Author and books. For example, we want to check if this an new author which doesn't have any books written.

```
SELECT authors.id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN books ON authors.id = books.author_id AND books.id IS NULL
```

This will work properly in any RDBMS: MySQL, PostgreSQL, SQL Server, maybe Oracle, but not in SQLite3. In SQLite3 the last part needs to be moved to `WHERE`:

```
SELECT authors.id
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN books ON authors.id = books.author_id
WHERE books.id IS NULL
```

to work properly. Why?

Comment: Toy databases are like that. They work for an overwhelming majority of use cases, making them enormously useful, but one needs to learn to live with their many shortcomings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are incorrect that the version with the condition in the `ON` clause does any filtering.  For instance, [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/afa7df/1) is a MySQL SQL Fiddle that shows that putting the condition in the `ON` clause returns two rows.

This is the correct way to get authors with no books, using `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT authors.id
FROM authors LEFT JOIN
     books
     ON authors.id = books.author_id
WHERE books.id IS NULL;
```

This filters out authors that have books, leaving the authors with no books.  The logic of `LEFT JOIN` is simple:  Keep all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` conditions evaluates to true, false, or `NULL`.

Putting the condition in the `ON` clause has a different logic.  It will return *all* authors.  There is no filtering.

I have a vague recollection that some versions of some databases have a bug where such a constant expression is treated as a filtering clause.  However, that is not correct.  What you think of as the "exception" is correct and should work in any database.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I think I've mistaken it with `INNER JOIN`, if it is `INNER JOIN` then those conditions in `ON` work same as in `WHERE` as I remember.